# Specify which library (.so) file to use

Tags: python, pyside, shared-libraries

On a Linux machine I have a Python (PySide) program that needs `libQtWebkit.so` as library. By default it uses the system-wide installed version found in `/usr/lib`. However, this is not the correct version of this library.

The program has its own custom version of the `libQtWebkit.so` file, which it needs to use. But I don't want to install this custom libary file system-wide into `/usr/lib`.

So my question is: How can I tell the Python program to use a specific (local) `.so` file instead of the globally installed one?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use LD_LIBRARY_PATH to tell the loader were to look first for shared libraries.

If the .so is in the current directory, you can invoke python as follows:

LD_LIBRARY_PATH=.:$LD_LIBRARY_PATH  python

See [shared libraries howto](http://tldp.org/HOWTO/Program-Library-HOWTO/shared-libraries.html)